# com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 587; timeout -1

Tags: java, spring, email, smtp, gmail

I had implemented the ability to send email to Java. However, from the moment I get the following error:

```
DEBUG SMTP: need username and password for authentication
DEBUG SMTP: protocolConnect returning false, host=smtp.gmail.com, user=USERNAME, password=<null>
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 587, isSSL true
com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 587; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

I think my code is not wrong. Because my code works well on my two colleagues' PC. (telnet smtp.gmail.com 587) command works well.

Help me please. I could not do anything for a few days because of this.

I am a beginner and I would appreciate it if you could let me know.

Answer (score 0):

According to this :

> "Because my code works well on my two colleagues' PC. (telnet
>   smtp.gmail.com 587) command works well"

i assume that you already authorize access through less secure app in the gmail account you're using, and the problem is related to your own computer.

**Did you check your firewall or antivirus rules ?**

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: yes @kk, but to be able to help him, we need (more information) to better understand the problem right ?
i was just suggesting what i think can help him progress in his solution searching.

Ps: because of my reputation i could not yet make comments, so the only way i had was to post an answer.